# Is there a shorthand byte notation in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

It’s been awhile since I programmed in C/C++. For the life of me, I cannot remember (or find in Google) how to make the following work. I thought there was a shorthand way of writing a repeating string of bytes, like these:

```
0x00 => 0x00000000
0xFF => 0xFFFFFFFF
0xCD => 0xCDCDCDCD
```

For example, if I was to declare

```
int x = 0xCD;
printf("%d", x);
```

it would print `3452816845`, not `205`.

Am I going crazy?

Is it possible without doing runtime bit shifts (e.g., by making the preprocessor handle it)?

Comment: Nothing of this sort exists.

Comment: @Justin: One of us is going crazy, and I don't think it is me!  :-)  What kind of shorthand do you think it might be?  A format conversion?  A repetition factor in a declaration?  An implied loop?

Comment: It's hard to imagine such a feature in C or C++ if only because there aren't many places where it would be useful.

Comment: I just want to write integer constants that have the same two bytes repeating for the whole integer.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I could have sworn I used these to create masks when I was doing a bit-twiddling exercise in college.  Maybe we were working with shorts?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't Perl ?

Comment: There's a very simple direct solution. See my answer.

Comment: 0x00 is already shorthand for 0x00000000. I always have problems counting 0's so I find that one quite useful.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of Verilog (and other HDLs) here. Considering that language is rather c-like especially with its extensions it's probably not THAT strange.

Comment: Thanks all.  Unfortunately none of these are what I had in mind (was trying to avoid generating more instructions than necessary for my shorthand).  I know it can be done with a macro, but I thought said macro was standard.

Comment: Are you confusing C++ with CSS? Both allow `/*` for comments, but otherwise they're reasonably different languages. CSS allows for hex shorthands, but it doesn't have multiple inheritance (though it does know about classes).

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way is:

```
0x1010101u * x
```

I can't think of any syntax that could possibly be simpler or more self-explanatory...

**Edit:** I see you want it to work for arbitrary types. Since it only makes sense for unsigned types, I'm going to assume you're using an unsigned type. Then try

```
#define REPB(t, x) ((t)-1/255 * (x))
```

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing like that by default in C. There's something similar in CSS (the color `#123` is expanded to `#112233`), but that's completely different. :)

You could write a macro to do it for you, though, like:

```
#define REPEAT_BYTE(x) ((x) | ((x) << 8) | ((x) << 16) | ((x) << 24))
...
int x = REPEAT_BYTE(0xcd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you write your own macro, this is impossible. How would it know how long to repeat? `0xAB` could mean `0xABABABABABABABABABABAB` for all it knows (using the proposed idea).

Comment: It would repeat it depending upon the type.

Comment: If this is necessary, use a macro as suggested by me and duskwuff.

Comment: @Justin:  No, it wouldn't.  C and C++ don't initialize that way.  There is the type of the initializer, and the type of the variable, and ways to convert from the one to the other.  The value and type of the initializer are not affected by the variable type.  Are you sure you're thinking of C or C++?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such shorthand. 0x00 is the same as 0. 0xFF is the same as 0x000000FF.

Comment: ...although `0x00` is hex and `0` is octal. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use some template trickery:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, unsigned char Pattern, unsigned int N=sizeof(T)>
struct FillInt
{
    static const T Value=((T)Pattern)<<((N-1)*CHAR_BIT) | FillInt<T, Pattern, N-1>::Value;
};

template<typename T, unsigned char Pattern>
struct FillInt<T, Pattern, 0>
{
    static const T Value=0;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<hex<<FillInt<unsigned int, 0xdc>::Value<<endl; // outputs dcdcdcdc on 32 bit machines
}
```

which adapts automatically to the integral type passed as first argument and is completely resolved at compile-time, but this is just for fun, I don't think I'd use such a thing in real code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use such a thing in real code? Just today I was bitten by having a constant written `0xFFFF` for a u16 (and it was conceptually "the byte `0xFF` repeated N times), but then the type switched to u32, and the constant became wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  But you can use memset:

```
int x;
memset(&x, 0xCD, sizeof(x));
```

And you could make a macro of that:

```
#define INITVAR(var, value) memset(&(var), (int)(value), sizeof(var))
int x;
INITVAR(x, 0xCD);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preprocessor token concatenation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define multi4(a) (0x##a##a##a##a)

int main()
{
    int a = multi4(cd);
    printf("0x%x\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0xcdcdcdcd
```

Of course, you have to create a new macro each time you want to create a "generator" with a different number of repetitions.